# Using firebase realtime database with react router 6+

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, react-router-dom

I'm building a simple scheduling app hoping to use React Router 6+ and Firebase Realtime Database. I can't figure out how to get these two tools to work together to fetch data correctly.

My code currently looks like this:

`main.js`:

```
...
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <App></App>, errorElement: <ErrorPage /> },
  {
    path: "/event/:eventUUID",
    element: <EventPage />,
    loader: eventLoader,
  },
]);
...
```

`eventPage`:

```
export const loader = async ({ params }) => {
  const singleEvent = await getSingleEvent(params.eventUUID);
  console.log(singleEvent); //logs null
  return singleEvent;
};

export const EventPage = () => {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  return <>{data?.eventname}</>;
};
```

`firebase function:`

```
export const getSingleEvent = async (eventID) => {
  const database = getDatabase();
  const singleEventRef = ref(database, "event/" + eventID);
  onValue(singleEventRef, (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val()); //logs the data I expect to see
    const data = snapshot.val();
    return data;
  });
  return null;
};
```

I would expect based on the React Router docs that `useLoaderData` would intelligently wait for the loader to pull the data, then render my component based on the data. But this does not appear to be happening; I get null no matter what.
I've futzed around with React.Suspense as well as the Await component in React Router 6; nothing seems to help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `getSingleEvent` function only ever returns a `null` value, the `return data` only returns a value from the `onValue` success handler, you'd still need to return this returned value from the outer function scope.

What I typically do is convert success/failure callback syntax into Javascript Promise that either resolves/rejects.

Example:

```js
const onValuePromise = ref => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => onValue(ref, snapshot => resolve(snapshop.val()), reject)
);
```

```js
export const getSingleEvent = async (eventID) => {
  const database = getDatabase();
  const singleEventRef = ref(database, "event/" + eventID);

  try {
    const data = await onValuePromise(singleEventRef);
    return data;
  } catch(error) {
    // handle or ignore errors and rejected promises
    return null;
  }
};
```

A potential issue I see with using the `onValue` utility in the loader function is that is instantiates a listener to the remote resource and calls the success/failure callbacks when the resource updates, and returns an unsubscribe function that should be called to remove the subscription. It's a way to eliminate resource (*memory, callbacks, etc*) leaks.

You should probably use the `get` method to fetch/read data only once, and then you'll not need to be concerned with open subscriptions.

However, it appears the `onValue` observer takes also an options object to specify a "read only once" property.

See [Read data once with an observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_an_observer)

> ```
> import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";
> import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
>
> const db = getDatabase();
> const auth = getAuth();
>
> const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
> return onValue(ref(db, '/users/' + userId), (snapshot) => {
>   const username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
>   // ...
> }, {
>   onlyOnce: true
> });
> ```

We can tweak the previous code to also pass/consume query options:

```js
const onValuePromise = (ref, options => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => onValue(ref, snapshot => resolve(snapshop.val()), reject, options)
);
```

```js
export const getSingleEvent = async (eventID) => {
  const database = getDatabase();
  const singleEventRef = ref(database, "event/" + eventID);

  try {
    const data = await onValuePromise(singleEventRef, { onlyOnce: true });
    return data;
  } catch(error) {
    // handle or ignore errors and rejected promises
    return null;
  }
};
```